# Comparator Function in Adapter on Float values

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, comparator

I'm getting distance from my database and I want to sort my data like the shortest distance in list should be shown in RecyclerView first.
I have implemented comparator in m Profile model class like this :

```
public class Profiles implements Comparator<Profiles>
```

then override the method in model class :

```
 @Override
    public int compare(Profiles profiles, Profiles t1) {
        return Float.compare(profiles.getDistance(), t1.getDistance());
    }
```

Now in my class where I'm setting the adapter I'm not getting which list should be pass to **Collections.sort()** as I'm giving it the List of type Profile and it giving me this error :

`no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Profiles>) method  Collections<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable`

this is what I'm doing in my RecyclerView class

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Profiles profiles = ds.getValue(Profiles.class);
                    profiles.setDistance(distanceFunc());
                    String covid = (String) ds.child("covid_recovered").getValue();
                    String dengue = (String) ds.child("dengue_recovered").getValue();
                    for (DataSnapshot option : ds.child("matched_bloodGroups").getChildren()) {
                        canDonateBG.add(String.valueOf(option.getValue()));
                    }
                    if (canDonateBG.contains(bloodGroup)) {
                        if (recoverey != null) {
                            if (covid.equals(covidRecover)) {
                                list.add(profiles);
                                canDonateBG.clear();
                            } else if (dengue.equals(dengueRecover)) {
                                list.add(profiles);
                                canDonateBG.clear();
                            }
                }
              
                Collections.sort(list);

                donarAdapter = new DonarAdapter(DonarList.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(donarAdapter);
            }
```

So which list should I pass to sort function as it's not accepting the list of type Profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) there two sort methods the `sort` that you're calling which is `sort(List<T> list)` expects you to implement `Comparable` not `Comparator` it sorts the element in natural ordering by calling `compareTo()` method if they come from library like the `String` class. The sort you're calling can not find that method because you have `compare()` not `compareTo()`

The one that takes a `Comparator` is `sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`
in your case you can use it like `Collections.sort(list,this)` instead of `Collections.sort(list)` if you want to use `Comparator` only otherwise you can implement `Comparable` and override `compareTo`  and it is not like it will not take `Profiles` list it will take any it just should implement the correct interface

i will suggest to do it like below in that case you don't have to implement any interface **In java 8 or above**

```
Collections.sort(list,(profiles,t1) -> Float.compare(profiles.getDistance,t1.getDistance())
```

or **below java 8**

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator()<Profiles>{
@Override
public int compare(Profiles profiles,Profiles t1){
   return Float.compare(profiles.getDistance,t1.getDistance);
  });
```

**have a good day Umair Iqbal**

Comment: Thanks, man it worked.
Can you please elaborate this
Collections.sort(list,(profiles,t1) -> Float.compare(profiles.getDistance,t1.getDistance())
is it a function or how it working like how it's returning the comparable value and what if I have to show value in descending order right now its in ascending order

Comment: i think you don't know about lambda expression , i am editing the answer and then explaining a bit

Comment: previously is was a shorthand which i edited now, the compiler knows second argument take Compartor so don't mention that, it also know there is only one method which is compare to so also don't mention that , it also know what type of argument that method take so you also don't have to mention that the only thing that compiler doesn't know is what is after -> so we just provide that , this is a bit simplified so need to learn about lambda expression to know what exactly are they and what else you can do with them , they are awesome using them can make code more concise and readable

Comment: learn more about them https://youtu.be/f4QZ12wMQO8 also watch other videos of its playlist

Comment: to do descending just do `Float.compare(t1.getDistance(),profiles.getDistance())` basically just switch the parameters, because intalnally it is doing someting like `return  profiles.getDitance > t1.getDistance()`